# Direct logout link

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, login

I know I can display the login/logout form with the following link:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&view=login
```

But once logged in, this link will redirect the user to a page with a logout button that has to be clicked.

Is it possible to create a link that will log out the current user directly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following link is for direct logout:

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout
```

But a user token is required in order to avoid an error message `Invalid Token`, and some PHP magic is required in order to get the token. The following code will display a `Login` link to guests, and a direct `Logout Username` link to logged in users:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest)
{
    echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_users&view=login">Login</a>';
}
else
{
    $userToken = JSession::getFormToken();
    echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&' . $userToken . '=1">Logout '  . $user->username . '</a>.';
}
```

The code can be included in any extension, or using a plugin/module that allows inserting PHP code directly (e.g. [DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/directphp), [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-html-advanced), [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/sourcerer) or similar).

Comment: Haha, too obvious...? Sorry about that. To be fair, though, I find the code snippet quite usefull, and use it all the time on client websites to have a small, non-intrusive login link in the footer. I just wasn't sure about what to ask in order to post the code.

Comment: +1 Extremely useful! How can you make a redirect to a specific page after it? is there some `&additional_parameter` that can be used to allow a redirect after logout?

Comment: Hey there thanks for this! Can you provide some documentation where this is explained a bit more in detail? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There is already a plugin which works great for logout button.

You should check this extension [logout button](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/logout-button)

Answer (score 7):

As a final answer, Joomla has a builtin "Logout" menu item, added to core I think around 3.4* maybe 3.5.  So now you don't need any additional plugins.

The logout menu item also allows for a redirect on logout.

Also if you set your Login menu item to 'Guest' access and your Logout menu item to 'Registered' access, the menu change depending on your status.

Detailed SE answer here:
[Change Login to Logout](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16023/change-login-to-logout)

Comment: This is probably the best approach for websites using an up to date version of Joomla since it only uses Joomla core functionalities. If you really need to programmatically create a logout link, however, the "accepted answer" is a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

As a third option, there is a **[Quick Logout](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/quick-logout)** component which adds a direct logout menu item in Joomla and will logout the users without the confirmation.

It also provides the option to set redirection to a desired page after logout.

Answer (score 3):

I found that on Joomla 3.9.22, a link to `/component/users/?task=user.logout` worked as a logout link that did not require a userToken. When I used `index.php?option=com_users&view=login&layout=logout&task=user.menulogout`, it instead forwarded to a page containing only a logout button.