# Change Login to Logout

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, login, joomla-3.5

I have a website using Joomla 3.5 and I currently have a 'Login' main menu item. Once a User logs in, there are some sub-menu items that appear under the 'Login' menu item.

What I want to do is to change the menu item name from 'Login' to 'Logout' and point it to another page so they can actually log out.

Comment: To all German administrators: The translation of Logout is 'Anmelden' instead of 'Abmelden'. When I previously looked at this feature I omitted to read the small print:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Good Folks at OSTraining just published this nice [Tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/login-and-logout/):

#### Step #1. Create the Login link

- Go to Menus > your menu > Add New Menu Item

[image: Create the Login link]

- Enter a Menu Title.
- Select the Menu Item Type.

[image]

- Choose Users > Login Form.

[image]

- Set "Access" to "Guest"
- Click "Save & New".

Guest access will make it so that it only appears to non-logged-in users. If for some reason your site doesn't have Guest access, you can use [this tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/hiding-content-from-logged-in-users/) to create it.

[image]

#### Step #2. Create the Logout link

Next, let's create the Logout link.

- Create a new menu item.
- Enter a Menu Title.
- Select the Menu Item Type.

[image]

- Choose Users > Logout.

This feature was added in Joomla 3.5. So if you don't have this option, you'd need to update to Joomla 3.5 or later.

[image]

- Switch "Access" to "Registered".
- Click "Save & Close".

[image]

#### Step #3. Test the links

Finally, let's test to make sure we got everything right.

Here are some things to check for:

- Does the "Login" appear when logged out?
- Does the "Logout" appear when logged in? Does it appear when logged
  in with another account of a different access level? If not, you may
  need to adjust the Access Control. We have a class on that at
  [Joomla's Access Control Levels](https://www.ostraining.com/class/acm/).

That's all there is to it. Congrats! Joomla 3.5 and higher makes it really easy to set up.

---

As always, thanx to OSTraining for best Joomla Tutorials out there.

Answer (score 3):

In Joomla! 3.5 we have a new menu item type called **Logout** in **Users** section,
 create a new menu item and select this new option, see the screenshot:

[image]

Regards.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have no problems creating a Log Out button and making that work, the issue I am having is I want the "LOGIN" menu item to disappear so that I can have another menu item in its place with a "LOGOUT" option within it.

The website in question is www.lsl.global

Comment: Hi Alex, I cleared my cache after making some changes to the User Access Levels and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the same thing on one of my sites.

Firstly, you should create a [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) for the **mod_login** module

Once done, you should have the following file:

> ROOT/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/mod_login/default_logout.php

***Note: The path may be slightly different depending on the template's framework.***

---

Then, Open the file mentioned above and add the following code

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#nav").find(".item-222 a").empty().text("Logout");

    });

');
```

You will of course need to change `#nav` to your menu wrapped selector and `.item-222 a` to the menu item selector.

If you provide a link to your site, I can give you the exact code used above, but until then, this is all I can provide.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I made changes to the User Access Levels but these didnt appear to be working, I have since cleared my cache and now the website appears to be working how I wanted to.

**FOR USER ACCESS LEVELS:**

1. PUBLIC: leave all options unchecked
2. GUEST: checked Guest only
3. REGISTERED: checked Manager, Registered User and Super User

**FOR THE MENU ITEMS:**

1. MAIN MENU: User Access Level set to 'Public' by default
2. LOGIN: Changed User Access Level to 'Guest'
3. ADMIN with Sub-Menu Items: Changed all User Access Levels to 'Registered', this includes my "logout" button.

Now when I login, the menu updates correctly.